# why .offset() position is unpredictable

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset

I encountered this issue during a project:

I'm implementing this function: when an element A is clicked, another element B will be shown beside A. The code logic would be like this:

```
eleB.offset({top: eleA.offset().top, left: eleA.offset().left + eleA.width() + 10});
eleB.show();
```

in css

```
#eleB {
    position: absolute;
}
```

The position of element B seems unpredictable, not always staying with eleA. And when I print out the offset of eleB, the numbers seems from nowhere. And each time the position is different even though eleA never changes.

I used .css() as an alternative which works pretty well.

Just want to know why the .offset() got some unpredictable output.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a demo where the issue is credible and visible?

Comment: This sounds like human error. `offset()` is fairly predictable, but odd dom structures can make it hard to reason about. Could you put up a jsfiddle demonstrating the behavior?

Comment: "The .offset() setter method allows us to reposition an element. The element's position is specified relative to the document. If the element's position style property is currently static, **it will be set to relative to allow for this repositioning**." <- Maybe this is a clue? Is your element still set to `absolute` when you use offset?

Comment: jQuery documentation lists some caveats: padding, margin or border settings on the `body` element, fractional return values, page zoom in browser

Answer (score 0):

`.offset()` is the element's position relative to the `document` boundaries.

If `A` offsetTop is let's say `800`, clicking on `A`, the `B` element you try to position to `top: A-offset` will go well... to that top position.
If it's inside a parent somewhere in the page, that `800px` top will not match the `A`'s position.
If you put `B` directly as a `<body>` child than that 800 px top B moved will match the exact A position

***[Same parent - demo](http://jsbin.com/neboxi/1/edit)***
***[B in body - demo](http://jsbin.com/neboxi/3/edit)***